# mysql query to find specific word that might start with different letters?

Tags: mysql

This should be easy although I cannot seem able to find it somewhere. myabe because i am terrible at explaining it

Say i want to search for that ***ENDS*** with "at" but it either starts with letter c or b

how would the query look like?

The closest thing I saw is this but it does **not** work:

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title LIKE '[ac]at'
```

I want it to return

cat

bat

If you are wondering why I need this, I am dealing with arabic letters so I need this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title RLIKE '[ac]at'
```

Comment: Thanks,It worked using the RLIKE, Is there any way to do it using MATCH(title) AGAINST ('[ac]at')? because I am indexing `title`. I tried it but it seems it does not work

Comment: No, unfortunately the fulltext indexing only matches whole words, not patterns.

Answer (score 0):

to add another option (although i like regex i think the best here)...

you can look for at at the end of the string with

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title LIKE '%at'
```

you may also do some `SUBSTR` and `RTRIM` tricks to get just the end characters, and compare directly to those with no wildcards..

Comment: sorry but i need specific letters at the beginning not all letters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your after, but there a very interesting [article here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) about how easy it is to write a spelling checker / corrector.

Its python but its fascinating.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title LIKE '%at%'
```

Comment: sorry but i need specific letters at the beginning not all letters. plus nothing after "at"

Comment: This will not do what he want I'm afraid.